# Question about code smell related to data class and long parameter list

Tags: data-class, long-parameter-list

Both data class and long parameter list are considered as code smell. However, the solution is of long parameter list smell is to create parameter objects. Is parameter objects the same as data class? If so, the solution will introduce data class smell.

Answer (score 0):

See on Stack Exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338195/why-are-data-classes-considered-a-code-smell

Creating a DTO, a "dumb object" only to hold some data is not necessarily a code smell. But often, after extracting some parameters into a data object, you might realize that some logic or other behavior can be moved from the client into this data object.

After this happens, the data class code smell comes up when this class has methods but also exposes some of its internal fields. In that case, the internal data should be encapsulated, access restricted as much as possible.

My personal opinion is that this is less of a problem in languages or frameworks where the class instance and its fields are immutable. For example, in functional programming, the generic approach is to create functions (methods) that operate on immutable data types. In this case, allowing access to some immutable data or fields poses less problems.